# How to detect the end of the current process?

Tags: python, oop, metaprogramming

As you may know, Python objects have a `__del__` method. This method may or may not be called once your process stops. As such you must not use it to free resources.

Most people would tell you to use with-statements (or try-finally). I use with-statements all the time and I love them, I even create objects with `__enter__/__exit__` all the time, but in my very specific case, it won't do.

**Is there a way for an instance of an object to detect when its process ends?**

```
import my_module as db

class Connection:
    def __init__(self, config: db.config.DatabaseConfiguration):
        self.connection = db.connect(config)

    def __del__(self):
        self.connection.disconnect()

    # def __finally__(self) ?  Something to trigger when root context ends ?
```

My bet is that it could be done with some good old Python meta-programming.

Context:
I work on a module that will be used by others. I can't go in their code and add with-statements.

Comment: You might want to look up `atexit` in the Python documentation. https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html

Comment: Question solved. Thank you!